# Books on the Existence of G-d?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, theology

I was wondering if anyone would be able to recommend to me books from a Jewish perspective on the existence of G-d. Something along the lines of proving G-d's existence. I would prefer an evidentiary book, perhaps drawing on Jewish History, archeology, or science. I have already read Rabbi Meir Simcha Sokolovsky's "Prophecy and Providence" (which I would highly recommend), but I was left wanting more examples.

Comment: like this? http://www.amazon.com/Permission-To-Believe-Approaches-Existence/dp/0944070558

Comment: @Danno That is an interesting book, but I am looking more for an evidentiary approach.

Comment: Moshe, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I like your use of the word "first" for this post, which [implies](http://www.ou.org/about/judaism/sheshet.htm) that you expect to produce more. :) Please [edit] as much detail about what you're looking for (e.g. "evidentiary" and what you mean by that) into the question to make it as likely as possible to get answers that will address what you're looking for.

Comment: Issac, I edited the post to be more descriptive and specific. Thanks for the for the input!

Answer (score 4):

Classic sources: Guide for The Perplexed, Duties of The Heart & The Kuzari.

The contemporary book "Challenge" by Aryeh Carmell seems to be rather popular. A rather different approach is taken by Walter Wurzburger in his "God is Proof Enough"- though I would suggest read the reviews (for example: http://aiwac.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/religion-for-grown-ups-on-r-dr-walter-wurzburger/ ) first, since Rabbi Wurzburger's style is different then the other volumes mentioned here.

Answer (score 4):

"Permission to Believe: Four rational approaches to G-d's existence" and "Permission to Receive: Four rational approaches to the Torahs divine origin" by Lawrence Kelemen. Although not thorough it gives a good introductory insight into some of the arguments that are used in 'proof of G-d' discussions.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31712/books-on-the-existence-of-g-d/31740#comment82049_31712

Answer (score 3):

Rav [Noach Weinberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah_Weinberg) has a phenomenal shiur series proving His existence in a number of different ways, they can be listened [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c4vvft79gzn32lt/AABl72vhKPhV8B-Dxw2ahRCta?dl=0) for free.

They are strongly recommended for anyone and everyone from every walk of Jewish life.

Answer (score 3):

chovos halevavos/duties of the heart - [shaar yichud](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=398) / Gate #1 Unity of God

Gate #2 also, but it focuses on reflecting on nature.

I personally have benefited tremendously from the shaar yichud. it's very powerful but only if you really study it in depth.

Comment: Is this book "evidentiary" (as outlined in the question)?

Comment: yes. the evidence is that the universe exists, hence there must be something eternal otherwise this would not be the case, rather nothing would exist. From there he demonstrates that which is Eternal must be of completely different nature than anything we are familiar with. see there for more.

Comment: That doesn't sound at all like  an evidentiary (as the OP defined it) book. Sounds much more philosophical.

Comment: I think the existence of the non-eternal is evidence something eternal created it. You cant have direct evidence for God since he is eternal and the eternal is above time and that which is above time is above space since the two are inextricably intertwined. hence God is inherently unknowable and unscientific. we can only deduce His existence from indirect evidence, i.e. the effect He manifests.

Comment: I'm not trying to dispute his argument here. But I don't think it is of the class of proofs that the OP sought, such as those "drawing on Jewish History, archeology, or science." He wants _teleological_ proofs, not cosmological proofs. It doesn't matter if you find the latter class more convincing or not.

Comment: he asked for evidence. i think that's the only evidence possible. once you start asking for tangible evidence for that which is inherently intangible, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: Like I said, I don't care if you think it's the only evidence possible. He asked for a very specific kind of evidence. If you don't have any to offer then don't answer.

Comment: i disagree with you. he asked for evidence, i gave him evidence. to you it seems vague philosophical evidence, to me it seems like clear evidence.

Comment: and there is no other possible explanation

Comment: I don't care if it is vague or clear. It isn't what was asked for. I don't care it it's unique. It isn't what was asked for. I don't care if you think it's a great proof. It isn't what was asked for.

Comment: we're not communicating. to me it's clear evidence. here's more evidence from eminent scientists if you like http://theoligarch.com/richard-dawkins-aliens.htm

Comment: Of course we're not communicating. You aren't listening. It isn't the _kind_ of evidence he wanted. Can you accept that there are different _kinds_ of evidence?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read it, but Living Up to the Truth by Rabbi Dr. Dovid Gottlieb seems to fall under what you're looking for and is available for free at http://ohr.edu/992.

Comment: read this book a while ago. its worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

An "evidentiary book, perhaps drawing on Jewish History"?!?

"from a Jewish perspective"?

There's this book on my shelf, often read, divided into 3 main subsections, that shows HaShem's influence on Jewish History.....

Good "proof" testimonies at Shemot 19, Devarim 5:3 "not with our fathers but with US, even US, who are all of us alive this day" !!!   Powerful stuff.

If you don't accept the validity of the original testimony, from the original witnesses, the commentaries probably won't help much...