What is the best philosophical argument for G-d?
I am currently struggling with my faith at the moment and I have been now for a few weeks on and off, it has gotten to the point where I have gotten depressed, so I thought that I would reach out to ask, what is the best philosophical evidence for G-d's existence?

Personally, I don’t think there’s any single piece of evidence or any singular argument that is sufficient for arguing for God’s existence or his nature. It is the cumulative effect of many arguments, personal experiences, and prayer that serve as one’s foundation for faith in God. And what one person finds compelling may not be for another. Personally, I am drawn to the beauty of the scriptures; they always find a way to challenge me and to cause me to grow deeper in my understanding no matter how many years I study and debate. Is there any particular matter that is causing you to doubt?

relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31712/11501

The Rambam's argument, as explained by R Manis Friedman, is the best: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTSHYXABAYI

While there are philosophical proofs, the main proof in Judaism is historical: that God revealed Himself at Mt. Sinai to the entire Jewish people. This is laid out in the opening chapters of Deuteronomy.
